# Lines in 3Ds Max to Make a surface object

Tags: 3dsmax, 3ds

I'm still a beginner in 3Ds Max.. I'm trying to draw this robot head in this way:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbtoH.jpg

When I make it "Surface" it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUpRo.jpg

There is something wrong in the front, my lines doesn't look like it looks when its surfaced. and all vertex are fused together.. can anyone help what would the problem be?

Comment: it looks like you added something like a turbosmooth or something. Can you give us some of your settings? It's been a while since I last used 3dsmax, but I remember having issues like this

Answer (score 0):

This is not poly modelling, the technique used is splines in combination with a surface modifier, it's an approximation to a nurbs workflow. The "problem" is in combination of the surface modifier and the splines, the modifier interpolates the curves, you should check out the bezier handles on the splines, I bet some off them are not aligned properly with the surface. If you can post an image with all bezier handles visible (select all verts).

As a tip/opinion, spline modelling in max is not as powerful as nurbs modelling in any other program. I would suggest learning poly modelling. More people do it, you'll find better support and tutorials too.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was because of Threshold, it was 1 I decreased it to 0.5 and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I should check Surface modifier. It build a mesh based on a line net. Lines can be modified with bezier points and its very powerful to model complex shapes.

It will fit very well if u have the isometric views of your original model (up, side, front), even better if you can draw some lines in model before taking a picture.

I used this technic modeling cars and the result was great.